# Relax, I’m Kidnapped! - Part 1

Tags: crossword-clues

You are known for making relaxing videos on YouTube. You are casually checking your mail, when suddenly, you find a crossword. After you receive it, you hear your dog barking. Someone is knocking on your door. You open it and you see a man in a black shirt, and then he throws you into a white minivan and put a very soft and relaxing bag on your head. You are kidnapped! He takes all your belongings and chews your ***Juicy Fruit*** gum. "Solve the crossword or ELSE," he booms. He takes off your bag and then he pulls out a piece of paper with the clues on it. You then look at your crossword:

[image: Crossword.]

This is the exact transcription of the paper he gave you:

Across

1. Disorganized pine cedar removes rad inventor/discoverer

7. Thorax parts, like a propeller

10. Kangaroo in short

11. Awareness is buried in Spanish juniper

12. Oh, triple!

13. Media of first sold, canned Idaho fruit indoors

14. City locks moth gone crazy

16. Rammed ground

17. Initial set user account

18. Enderman not on demand in Audible

19. Sitting but not sung in the future

20. Enlisted person has cut eerier craziness

23. Hang on, Ronnie!

Down

1. Sulfur out of control
2. I know where you live
3. __ Barto
4. Fruit too cheap knocked over last three peas and heads of abridgement and economy switched
5. Cooked icy sir out as a result of felicide
6. A time before instruments, there was mishandled tree fuel
7. Start of paperwork confuses ropers who are strong and successful
8. Cheering for them
9. False motion

13. Kiosk youthfully hidden in the heavens

15. Support, a pirate is surrounded by a first commander and one youth

21. Mud trashed hearing 'em

22. Yeah, broadcast!

*I made the crossword, hints and story by myself.*

Hint 1 (this is important later on):

> ***It has cryptic clues and normal clues mixed together.*** Most of it is cryptic clues.

Part 2: [Relax, I’m Kidnapped! - Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121605/relax-i-m-kidnapped-part-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This crossword is a bit unorthodox, but I did my best to just relax and go with the flow...

Grid:

> [image]

The shaded squares

> reading roughly from top right to bottom left spell out PEACE OF MIND, which is what we hopefully have after solving this puzzle!

Clue explanations, as far as I can tell:

> Clues are an eclectic mix of normal crossword clues, cryptics, wordplay, puns, and colloquialisms. If something didn't quite make sense I just kept calm and carried on.
>  Across
>  1. [NIEPCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nic%C3%A9phore_Ni%C3%A9pce): anagram of PINE CEDAR minus RAD, defn "inventor/discoverer"
>  7. [PROPLEURA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propleuron): defn is "thorax parts"; "like a propellor" since the two words look/sound somewhat similar
>  10. ROO: standard clue
>  11. AREN: hidden inside awARENess; for the definition, "[aren](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aren#Spanish)" is a conjugation of the Spanish verb "[arar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arar#Spanish)", which is a homonym for Spanish juniper
>  12. OOO: pun; triple of the letter "O" (arguably an &lit. definition)
>  13. SCI-FI: defn is "media"; first letters of Sold Canned Idaho Fruit Indoors
>  14. STOCKHOLM: anagram of LOCKS MOTH, defn "city"
>  16. [PISAY](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pisay): standard clue
>  17. SUA: first letters of Set User Account
>  18. ENER: one could argue that "demand" sounds ("Audible") like D-MAN and removing this from ENDERMAN gives the answer
>  19. ITT: SITTING minus SING ("sung in the future")
>  20. RECRUITEE: anagram of CUT EERIER; defn "enlisted person"
>  23. MAYDAY: reference to a phrase shouted during a [plane crash in Colorado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabernash,_Colorado#1984_airplane_crash)
>  Down
>  1. NOOO [SECA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_control_area): what you would say if you really wanted to emphasize the lack of emission control
>  2. IP: punny reference to an IP address ("where you live")
>  3. EL: standard clue
>  4. PEACH: defn is "fruit"; wordplay is a bit of a mess but it seems to be taking the last three letters of CHEAP, reversing them, moving to the front, then switching the E and the A
>  5. CURIOSITY: anagram of ICY SIR OUT; defn references "curiosity killed the cat"
>  6. ERE FLUTE: anagram of TREE FUEL, and "before instruments" = "ere flute"
>  7. PROSPER: first letter of Paperwork + anagram of ROPERS; defn "are strong and successful"
>  8. ROOTIN' EM: colloquialism
>  9. ANIMATE: seems to be a standard clue, doesn't quite match in tense
>  13. SKY: hidden in kioSK Youthfully; defn "the heavens"
>  15. CARRY: ARR ("a pirate") inside C and Y "first commander and one youth"; defn "support"
>  21. UD: MUD without the M ("em")
>  22. IA: could conceivably be a homophone "broadcast" of YEAH

Comment: By the way, the IP clue is actually a reference to the Garfield meme saying "I know where you live"