# Relax, I’m Kidnapped! - Part 2

Tags: wordplay, cipher

Part 1: [Relax, I’m Kidnapped! - Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121584/relax-i-m-kidnapped-part-1)

You manage to solve the [crossword](/questions/tagged/crossword), and you show your captor the answers. “Well, you solved it…but I’m not done yet. Go to my room,” he replies. He directs you to his room and shuts the door.
Taped to the wall was a piece of paper: 
*"Jbhyq 50bh gu5a10 5 jbhyq eryrnfr 50bh? Ar1re! 50bh j5yy ar1re or serr!"*

 There is a bed with a Mac. Safari is open and he has recently searched for some guy named ***Cooper Evan Smeer*** on Google. There was a random post-it on the camera: 
***VNOHEXFJRZPPQFWEEKBYZIPJTFFEKMKIXPYIH**EWGINNXEETRQKKMJNPEYARKOVHINPUXARP*
Strangely, it smells like vinegar, or maybe it’s the bottle of vinegar labelled as “***Revenge if I, (am not) Ed Pithier***" that's all empty. I explore his notes on the Mac and I find only one with the following: 
 *vehfvgjngfzlqjvrkjlg**shyegubpvymtmtwi***
HE, WORDY ELM, VAST TRIM
***JZQEC 1*** will tell you *jpe yp be gtrr and waxlow*
You sleep on his bed because he told you to do so if you needed some rest, or as he called it, "**decrypting out codes subconsciously.**" He then told you he was going to buy some more vinegar and Post-Its…and then you sleep in a warm, comfy bed with a pillow reading "*YGPOFQOYBOPOZWSSOKJLVWUNFAIGDBCSXKZELARXZOPXDXUOKQOKYMUNWKLAKHYFJBREBEYZWKNSAOPPFAIADOLOYXYOZBOCJKKZVAPHLOKIZLN*" on your head…zzzzzzzzzzzz…

Hint 1:

> You saw him pour vinegar on the "wordy elm" post-it...he muttered something about last time, in hint 1...

Hint 2:

> *"HITAW EMOFGURQ THE" ROL QEK N SN TI SESD UAN ESPRNH EÆPSILIÆ SN "ANMWNR N" TNHT EUOÆ MNKEN*

Hint 3:

> The names you seek is all too cool - until they're destroyed, but they're still understood.

*This whole puzzle is made by myself.*

Part 3: Please solve this for Part 3.

Comment: Can you clean up the question a bit? There are a lot of codes to decode but they are all mixed together in the flavor text, it's slightly an eyesore.

Comment: Okay............

Comment: Vinegar!? Well, no one is going to say that it is not Vigenere!

Comment: @1357924680a Well, it’s a bit of an easy one…

Comment: The coincidence index is about 0.04, which seems like a Vignere Cipher is needed

Comment: Hint two is a substitution ciphah!

Comment: @1357924680a No. (the following may be too much) Hint: Beheaded horse gains new thousand to develop code

Comment: Because many would-be codebreakers have driven themselves mad trying to make sense of a failed decipherment through anagrams and abbreviations, I'll kindly ask that you not mix anagrams and ciphers in the future.